# Screen black for a moment AMD

Tags: screen, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I'm facing an issue with ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on my Laptop (HP Zbook firefly G10).
The system has an AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 7840HS with radeon 780m graphics and 32 GB of RAM.

Basically, the screen goes black for a moment and then comes back on.
This happens often while gaming or web-browsing but I didn't find a way to reproduce it every-time, it appears to be random.

Moreover, before I also had a screen flickering issue that i solved by setting `amdgpu.sg_display=0` as a kernel parameter.

Here my system :

```
6.5.0-25-generic #25~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Feb 20 16:09:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is what I get with `lspci | grep VGA`

```
c3:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Phoenix1 (rev d4)
```

In Settings->About under Graphics I have this info :

```
GFX1103_R1 (gfx1103_r1, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.54, 6.5.0-25-generic)
```

I'm really new to linux and ubuntu so I don't really know how to solve this issue.
I tried to search on forums but I didn't find anything that could help me fix this.

Thank you in advance! :)